# application crashed with ANR:: IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification.

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter, android-filter

I created a listview with adapter. Implemented search with filter. It is working fine. But sometimes application is crashing with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes.
```

In ListView activity I am using the below code to invoke search when user types something in the textbox.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_view_layout);
    mAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this);
    ...

    mSearchEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_text);
    mSearchEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Log.v("ListViewActivity", "SearchTextBox: onTextChanged <" + s + ">");
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

In ListViewAdapter I used filter to implement search in the listview:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
private ArrayList<ListItem> mOriginalList;
private ArrayList<ListItem> mDisplayedList;

...

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            Log.v("ListViewAdapter", "Filter: publishResults constraint<" + constraint + ">");
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            Log.v("ListViewAdapter", "Filter: performFiltering constraint<" + constraint + ">");
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

            mDisplayedList.clear();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                mDisplayedList.addAll(mOriginalList);
                filterResults.count = mDisplayedList.size();
                filterResults.values = mDisplayedList;
            } else {
                String searchText = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                for (ListItem listItem : mOriginalList) {
                    if (listItem.getKeyName().toLowerCase().contains(searchText) 
                            || listItem.getKeyValue().toLowerCase().contains(searchText)) {
                        mDisplayedList.add(listItem);
                    }
                }

                filterResults.count = mDisplayedList.size();
                filterResults.values = mDisplayedList;
            }

            Log.v("ListViewAdapter", "Filter: performFiltering filterResults.count<" + filterResults.count + ">");
            return filterResults;
        }
    };

    return filter;
}
```

Comment: are you using notifyDataSetChanged() ??

Comment: Is in your adapter any static content or dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved. I moved the code to update mDisplayedList to publishResults() instead of keep on updating in performFiltering() for loop. Update mDisplayedList and call notifyDataSetChanged() together. I think this is the best solution.

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            Log.v("ListViewAdapter", "Filter: publishResults constraint<" + constraint + ">");

            if (results.count == 0) {
                mDisplayedList.clear();
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            } else {
                mDisplayedList.clear();
                mDisplayedList.addAll((ArrayList<ListItem>) results.values);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            Log.v("ListViewAdapter", "Filter: performFiltering constraint<" + constraint + ">");
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<ListItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<ListItem>();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(mOriginalList);
            } else {
                String searchText = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                for (ListItem listItem : mOriginalList) {
                    if (listItem.getKeyName().toLowerCase().contains(searchText) 
                            || listItem.getKeyValue().toLowerCase().contains(searchText)) {
                        filteredList.add(listItem);
                    }
                }
            }

            filterResults.count = filteredList.size();
            filterResults.values = filteredList;
            Log.v("ListViewAdapter", "Filter: performFiltering filterResults.count<" + filterResults.count + ">");
            return filterResults;
        }
    };

    return filter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use: `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Where should he needs to call ?

Comment: after onTextChanged()

Answer (score 0):

In `onTextChanged` , call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: No need to call. Because in `getFilter()` method already adapter beign changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes.
```

This problem occurs because of you'r set your adapter on main thread. Instead of you need to set your adapter in `UI thread`. Like with `AsyncTask` set adapter in `onPostExecute()` method or in `onHandledMessage()` method using `Handler` with `Thread`.